# Get contents of a file in a folder inside project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to access a file inside my project.

So I would create a new folder called `Files` and inside that folder contains various HTML files.

Is there anyway that I can access those files by going to `"Program/Files/file.html"` or similar.

Comment: Need more context here... though i suppose you want something like `Directory.GetFiles()`

Comment: Are you trying to access these files in your program or are you trying to import the files into your project?

Comment: May be you could explain a bit ..

Comment: Two things to consider: 1. what happens when you compile / deploy your project? will the folder be in the equivalent location to the compiled output, and 2. Are you reading / writing to these "Files", if you are only reading them, could you add them as embedded resources and extract as necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
using System.IO;
...

string folderPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; // or whatever folder you want to load..

foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.html"))
{
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
}
```